# Ruby on Rails: Validate contact form without model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple contact form that accepts the following fields (all should be required): Name, Email, phone, and message.

I also want to validate the email address.

Users should be given a response on whether or not the form submitted successfully, or if there are errors.

if so, display specific errors on the view.

This form is not connected to any database model. I'm not saving submissions. Only mailing.

I have a POST route set to `contact_form` in my PagesController

In my PagesController I have

```
    def contact_form
        UserMailer.contact_form(contact_form_params).deliver
    end
```

In my UserMailer class I have:

```
 def contact_form(params)
      @formParams = params;
      @date = Time.now
         mail(
            to: "support@example.com",
            subject: 'New Contact Form Submission', 
            from: @formParams[:email],
            reply_to: @formParams[:email],
        )
    end
```

This mails successfully, but there's no validation. I need to only run the mail block if validation passes. then return a response to the user.

Since I have no Model, I'm not sure how to do this. All the answers I see tell people to use `validates` on the ActiveRecord model.

With the few answers:

(note I've updated my params)

```
class UserMailerForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def initialize(options)
    options.each_pair{|k,v|
      self.send(:"#{k}=", v) if respond_to?(:"#{k}=")
    }
  end
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :message

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :message, presence: true
  validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP } 
end
```

```
 def contact_form
    @form = UserMailerForm.new(contact_form_params)

    if @form.valid?
      UserMailer.contact_form(contact_form_params).deliver
    else
     logger.debug('invalid')
     logger.debug(@form.valid?)
    end

  end
```

This sends mail when valid. However, I'm still unsure about sending info to the user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [make UserMailer a model](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) and [use validations on that](https://api.rubyonrails.org/).

```
class UserMailer
  include ActiveModel::Model       # make it a model
  include ActiveModel::Validations # add validations

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :message

  validates :name, :email, :phone, :message, presence: true
  validates :email, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP } 

  def send_mail(subject:, to:)
    mail(
      to: to,
      subject: subject, 
      from: email,
      reply_to: email,
    )
  end
end
```

Then use it like any other model.

```
def UserMailersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user_mailer = UserMailer.new
  end

  def create
    @user_mailer = UserMailer.new(params)
    if @user_mailer.valid?
      @user_mailer.send_mail(
        to: "support@example.com",
        subject: 'New Contact Form Submission',
      )
    else
      # Use @user_mailer.errors to inform the user of their mistake.
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

If you have multiple forms associated with UserMailer, you can make separate classes to validate each Form's inputs and then pass them along to UserMailer. You'd likely still want validations on UserMailer regardless.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question before I try to implement - where should this class file be placed?

Comment: I'm having an issue: `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: first_name, last_name, email, phone, message)` I changed some params, but they're all there in the UserMailerForm

Comment: @millman2394 I'd put it with `UserMailer`, probably in `app/services` or `app/lib`. You could make it `UserMailer::Form` and put it in `app/services/user_mailer/form.rb`. As for your error, I'd need to see how you're calling `UserMailerForm.new`.

Comment: i've edited my answer to show what i'm doing. Do you think you can expand on your answer in regards to showing invalid fields to the user on the form?

Comment: @millman2394 See edits. Making it an ActiveModel::Model should fix things.

Comment: thanks! that looks cleaner and it works. now I just need to display messages to the user. and discern which fields are invalid when @form.valid? fails

Comment: @millman2394 See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views The important thing is that you send the invalid @form object back to your `new` template and use `@form.errors` to display errors back to the user. Here is a rough sketch: https://gist.github.com/schwern/2cea64177f255d423cbb316de96e7bb7 A gem like [`simple_form`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) can make this a bit less tedious, but it's good to learn to do it manually a few times.

Comment: If you are using Rails 5 you should really use `ActiveModel::Attributes` instead of attr_accessor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ActiveModel::Validations` on your PORO the same way AR does this.

```rb
class MyFormObject
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  def initialize(options)
    options.each_pair{|k,v|
      self.send(:"#{k}=", v) if respond_to?(:"#{k}=")
    }
  end

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :phone, :message

  validates :name, presence: true
  # and so on...

end
```

Comment: I'm new to ruby and ruby on rails. Can you explain what your code is doing? Yours looks more complicated than the other answer

Comment: @millman2394 There was a small bug using `"${k}"` instead of `"#{k}"`. It does basically what mine does, but dynamically. It takes each pair you pass in to `new` and calls `self.key = value`, but only if the object has an accessor. This makes it behave like other Rails models.